# AlertDialog getActivity() error

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

I am building an Android app that uses AlertDialog. I am following Google's guide to building an AlertDialog, but it keeps giving me an error. I set an onClickListener on a FAB, but it either never works or it throws an error.

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab2);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            builder.setMessage("This is an alert dialog.").setTitle("alert dialog");
            builder.create();
        }
    });

}
```

But the Android Studio throws an error, saying:
"error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()"

I've tried declaring a context variable and passing that, tried using getApplicationContext(), and getApplication(), but they all don't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try a Clean/Rebuild?

Comment: If that code is in an Activity, you just need the current Activity instance; e.g., `ActivityName.this`.

Comment: you should also call show() on alertDialog builder. Reg error, is this code in Fragment ? If so, getActivity() should work. If not pass activity context to this class where this code is done and use it in builder. If it is within actiivty, just use this in builder.

Answer (score 2):

Everything seems to be correct but some minor tweaks required in your code.

If you are going to display the alert dialog in the **Activity use Activity.this** , if it is in **Fragment then use getActivity()** during initialization of AlertDialog.Builder(*****).

Write the logic of the alert dialog in a separate function and call them in your clicklistener. Below code will help you.

```
void showAlert(){

// If using activity use this 
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(*YOUR ACTIVITY NAME*.this);

// If using Fragment use this 
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

adb.setMessage("Alert Dialog Welcomes You");
adb.setTitle("Google alert dialog");  
AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
ad.show();
}
```

Then call it in your fab onclicklistener.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab2);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
           showAlert();
    }
});
```

Happy coding..!!

Answer (score 1):

If your class extend to **activity**, you should declare like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this);
```

If extend to **fragment**:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Android Studio is bugged in some way.  I would try to fix that by selecting "invalidate caches / restart" from the File menu.

That said, you can also get a context by getting it from the view.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
          //do your stuff here.
}
```